Role is unable to access S3 bucket
I am deploying a Kubernetes application in my live environment. I was trying to access my bucket through my IAM roles for service accounts (IRSA) that I have created. The role has all the permissions to access the bucket but in my jobs log, it gives the following error:
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied
/var/www/discourse/lib/s3_helper.rb:109:in `ensure_cors!'
/var/www/discourse/lib/tasks/s3.rake:191:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => s3:upload_assets

My IAM role has the following policy:
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc-abc-live",
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc-abc-live/*",
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

I used my stage environment IRSA to check if there’s any issue with the bucket. The bucket was accessible through my stage IRSA, meaning the bucket has no policy that blocks access to this role. I have also added the trust policy that allows the role to access resources in from the desired namespace. Any help would be appreciated.
I was trying to access my s3 bucket through irsa
